# Prevent connections to LDAP ports in Active Directory environment?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Situation:

- We have numerous Active Directory Domain Controllers (aka DCs) in our environment;
- We also have numerous IT specialists from other departments who bind Authentication of their services (mostly web-based apps) to **specific IP of specific DC** on port 389 instead of using Virtual IP or Load-Balanced A-record.

As the result, when single DC goes offline, also half of our infrastructure goes down with it.

Is there any way to prevent these unwanted direct LDAP connections (aka LDAP Binds) to our DCs? As I understand it we can't simply close **389|636** ports on firewall on DCs because then regular domain members like windows servers and workstations won't be functioning correctly. Netlogon and stuff. So is there any way from technical standpoint to force such connections through VIP|Load-Balancer and prevent direct connectivity?

Comment: If you have working VIP/load-balanced LDAP connectivity, why don't clients use those generally and you simply filter traffic to the dedicated IPs?

Comment: Specific _IP?_ Not even specific hostname? Does that mean they're using neither TLS nor Kerberos, just sending passwords in the clear?

Answer (score 3):

No, absolutely not. Furthermore, fronting AD with a load balancer is not supported. It *may* work in some scenarios with good citizen consumers, but 100% unsupported.

Active Directory does not provide an assurance of high availability or load balancing. Consuming applications have a responsibility to validate the connectivity and handle connectivity and availability issues, from design through to operations.

---

Some examples:

A lot of .NET managed code uses DirectoryEntry. After binding, DirectoryEntry maintains an affinity to a specific domain controller.

Server binds. It's possible to perform an LDAP bind with the server name/IP in the address. This is in the specification and cannot be ignored, and it is a preferred method of performing binds in complex and hostile environments.

The reason for this affinity is an object may have been recently created, and will not exist on other DC's yet. Or an attribute value was updated and that value was not replicated yet. So it is a *must* to maintain an affinity to a DC for anything where it's important to have actual accurate data and not crash due to connecting to a DC that has stale data.